# MS Project 2013 + ASP.Net +Sharepoint 2013-can i run web-part?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, sharepoint, ms-project

I investigate question about MS Project 2013+ASP.Net+Sharepoint 2013.

Can i build web part in Sharepoint 2013 and use MS Project 2013 at this web part?

And what mechanism i should use? 
Read that can use CSOM and PSI interface to access on MS Project.
But [this image](http://www.microsoftproject.ru/images/msproject2013/2.1_ProjectServer%202013_Architecture.png) talks that on ASPX pages uses HTTP(ok :) ) and PSI interface.

Please,tell me what API i should use to build ASP.Net-Sharepoint webpart with access to MS Project 2013?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,i can do it. I should use CSOM for modern versions of MS Projct(2013).